# Why does gawk printf give wrong round result?

Tags: awk, printf, gawk

The `printf` function of gawk works weired, for example:

```
gawk 'BEGIN { x=(57.3/6); printf("Result : \n\t%.0f\n\t%.1f\n\t%.2f\n\t%.3f\n",x, x,x,x) }'
```

It gives me:

```
    Result :
        10
        9.5
        9.55
        9.550
```

Obviously, the 2nd result was wrong, it should be **9.6**

my Gawk version is:

```
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 4.0.1 Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.
```

the C version `printf` performs normal:

```
$ cat tp.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
        float x;
        x=57.3/6;
        printf("Result:\n\t%.0f\n\t%.1f\n\t%.2f\n\t%.3f\n",x,x,x,x);
}

$ gcc tp.c -o tp
$ ./tp
Result:
        10
        9.6
        9.55
        9.550
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I found this from gawk mannual:

[How Round function works.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Round-Function.html)

It looks like one should write his own `rounding`   because the default `printf`'s perform depends upon upon the system’s C `sprintf()` subroutine, something like .5 will round to even, rather than always up.

Comment: Good find :-) The `awk` is not a tool specialized for Maths per se.. On the other hand languages like `python` or `ruby` are more flexible..

Comment: A bit heavy, but goes into details: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html